# Lower bound on numerical range in terms of real and imaginary parts

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.
Let $\text{W}$ denote the numerical range which is given by
\begin{align*}
\text{W}(B) = \{ \langle v, B v \rangle \mid \vert \vert v \vert \vert = 1  \}. 
\end{align*}
Suppose that I know $\text{W}(\text{Im}(A))$ and $\text{W}(\text{Re}(A))$, but I do not know $\text{W}(A) $.

It follows that  $\text{W}(A) \subset \text{W}(\text{Re}(A)) + i \text{W}(\text{Im}(A))$, but can I conclude any lower bound?

Comment: Have you tested $2\times 2$ matrices ?

Comment: $W(A)$ contains the convex hull of the eigenvalues of $A$, perhaps that's a helpful result here

Comment: Yes, I think one very important example to have in mind here is $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $. The numerical range is the unit disc and $0$ is the only eigenvalue. This shows that it is difficult to conclude something. The numerical ranges of real and imaginary parts are $\lbrack -1, 1 \rbrack $ so I can't expect to get the entire $ \text{W}(\text{Re}(A)) + i \text{W}(\text{Im}(A)) $ but I get some interpolation with the maximal values achieved.  That is the kind of bound I was hoping for.